# How to sum the numbers on the diagonal of a contingency table?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a contingency table:

```
a = c(1, 3, 4)
b = c(2, 3, 5)
a_b = data.frame(a, b)
lvls <- sort(unique(unlist(a_b)))
table(lapply(a_b, factor, levels = lvls))

   b
a   1 2 3 4 5
  1 0 1 0 0 0
  2 0 0 0 0 0
  3 0 0 1 0 0
  4 0 0 0 0 1
  5 0 0 0 0 0
```

I want to sum the numbers of the diagonal of the contingency table (in this case = 1), and get the proportion (in this case = 1/3 = 0.33), how can I achieve it? Thank you.

Comment: `sum(diag(table(lapply(a_b, factor, levels = lvls))))`

Comment: `sum(diag(tab))/sum(tab)` where `tab` is your results from `tab <- table(....)`

Comment: or `sum(a==b)` or `sum(a %in% b)` ?

Comment: @GKi OP wants proportions.

Comment: @jay.sf `sum(a==b) / length(a)` ?

Answer (score 2):

Try `mean` along with `==`

```
> mean(a == b)
[1] 0.3333333
```